# How to insert my X509 certificate signature in a xml

Tags: xml, certificate, x509, sign

I have an xml with data inside, but to send to the server I need it to have an x509 certificate (which I have installed on my machine).
The question is, I need to insert it in the same format as the example below, but I'm a newbie to it and looking on the details of my certificate, I really didn't understood what to do.

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="#assinar">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                    <ds:XPath>not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature)</ds:XPath>
                </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue></ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>
    </ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
        <ds:KeyValue>
            <ds:RSAKeyValue>
                <ds:Modulus>
                </ds:Modulus>
                <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
            </ds:RSAKeyValue>
        </ds:KeyValue>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
```

in the example that I have, the fields `<ds:Modulus>`, `<ds:X509Certificate>`, `<ds:SignatureValue>`, `<ds:DigestValue>` are in ASCII format (i guess), but mine is in hex.

Do I need to convert it? send to some URL and get the response?

Answer (score 0):

You might try base64-encoding the binary data, that's how it would be done with an email attachment. Does your API provider not show any samples?

Comment: Actually, the API provider documentation just said that it needs to be signed, and provided a xml as an example (the one I posted above). I have a certificate, but i don't know how to format it in the required parameters(those four I've written).

Comment: Is there a way to insert automatically my certificate in the corresponding xml?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/#sec-X509Data defines the ds:X509Certificate as the base64 encoding of the X.509 certificate.

Similarly, https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/#sec-RSAKeyValue describes Modulus and Exponent as being of type `CryptoBinary`.

https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/#sec-CryptoBinary says that the proper encoding is to convert the value to a byte array, remove any leading zero-value bytes, then base64 encode it.  I can say from experience that not all platforms remove the leading zeros, and not all platforms support reading the value if the leading zeros were removed.  So you can define how spec compliant you want to be here.

Absent any language tag or code, the best answer here is that all of your answers are defined in the XML Signature specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/.